# python Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, search, binary, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I'm trying to create a guessing game, but I'm running into some errors, can anyone help me?

```
A = A + [i]
# Define two variables which will be the end point of
# the search span 
mini = 0 
maxi = len(A) - 1 
stepcounter = 1 
find = int(input("Think of a number between 1 and 1000")) 
def guessgame(find, A, mini, maxi, stepcounter): 
    # This calculates the value of the midpoint element 
    # in the list guess = (A[mini] + A[maxi]) // 2 
    if guess == find: 
        return 
        print("You think of", guess, "I did this in", stepcounter, "number of steps") 
    elif guess < find: 
        mini = guess 
        stepcounter = stepcounter + 1 
        guessgame(find, A, mini, maxi, stepcounter) 
    elif guess > find: 
        maxi = guess 
        stepcounter = stepcounter + 1 
        guessgame(find, A, mini, maxi, stepcounter) 
    else: 
        return 
        print("Not in array") 
        guessgame(find, A, mini, maxi, stepc
```

ounter)

my error is

```
traceback most recent call last:
line 34 guessgame(find, a, mini,maxi, supercounter)

File "C:/Users/Acer VN7/PycharmProjects/untitled1/py.py", line 20, in guessgame
if guess == find:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: This is likely due to infinite recursion.  Hold on while I reformat and look at the code.

Comment: Alright, thanks. This means a lot

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you have is that you confuse the guess with its position.  You compute guess to be the midpoint of the values in **A**, but then you set mini or maxi to the *guess*, rather than its position.  I expect that this confusion drives your guess out of the binary search range, and you get an infinite recursion.

To debug this problem, add a few print statements to track execution.  For instance, the first line of your function should be something like

```
print find, mini, maxi
```

Then, when you compute guess and move one endpoint, print out those values before you leave the routine.

You seem to have omitted the code that puts values into **A**, so I'm not at all sure what's in there.

Beyond that, there are structural problems.  You can't get to the code after **return** in your **if** and **else** branches.  You can't get to the **else** branch at all, since the first three branches cover all possibilities (law of excluded middle).

Does this get you moving?